# SSRS 2008 R2 Insert Column outside group-Left is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I am building an SSRS report, that contains a Date column, a value column, and a row number column, The rows must be grouped by Date, and I managed to achieve this by creating a group based on the Date column, please check the image:
[image]

Now I just want to move the "SN" (Row number) column to the left to become the first column, I am doing this by right clicking on the time stamp column, and selecting "Insert column outside group-left", but this is not adding the column outside the group, the new column is being grouped inside the Time Stamp group: [image]

Any idea on how to move the right SN column to the left of the Date column, without merging it into the group.
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible, but one way to achieve your requirement would be to create a table link to the dataset and keep the TimeStamp Column between SN and Value and make sure that the `**HideDuplicates**` is set to `**TRUE**` for the same. Rest you can merge the cells using same border color and all.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple. You can create a new dataset selecting SN and Timestamp,order by timestamp.Now create a new tablix and select only SN field in it from the new dataset.Now merge the old tablix and the new one.